# What's better, a database for customers or a unified database?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity

How to have a single C# Application with Entity Framework that manages multiple schemas? Or should a single schema?

I have about 28 clients, I wonder if I keep each one with a separate database or unify in a single database and I manage the information the customer ID for example.

I worry that the volume of data hinder application performance. I use SQL Server 2014 currently each with a version of the system, we are evolving the system and desire suit the best scenario.

I believe that a single application controlled by client access login, be better to give maintenance.

I do not know if it is possible to have separate database, because I have some customers who like to have for security management of their own schema in their server.

How to create a context that gets the connection string dynamically, depending 
on the source of the request?

```
public class ProductRepository {

public void Add(Product product, int clientId)
{
   //Here the connection string will be set according to the client id you are saving information
   var context = ContextFactory.GetContext(clientId);
   context.Products.Add(product);

}

}
```

Or is it better to place within the entity customer ID that belongs to the information?

```
public class BaseEntity {

    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int Client_Id {get;set}
}


public class Products : BaseEntity{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public double Price {get;set;}

}
```

Comment: do you have an experienced DBA who will host the application ? sounds like you do not have an understanding on Distributed Applications especially in regards to housing / managing / supporting multiple clients. spend the money and pay an expert it will save you in the long run

Comment: The term database is unfortunately a bit ambiguous and I find the people sometimes use it to mean a table, schema, or an entire server instance. Could you clarify this? Are you wondering if you should host your clients in the same table? in the same schema? or in the same sql server instance?

Comment: sorry, the correct term is schema

Comment: Search for 'multi tenant database'. There are a number of write-ups on this, but *I encourage the use tenant-aware schema designs*. SQL Server is quite a beast and there are *many* ways to handle performance/scaling. We primarily use a single-schema multi-tenant approach, but some 'large clients' have their own databases instances (not databases, we keep schemes consistent across instances). In addition we also have some tenant-specific partitions. However, it would be *much* harder to go back the other way if starting from a "tenant unaware" schema.

Answer (score 3):

There are pros and cons to each side, but I prefer to separate database instances per client. This gives much more flexibility for customisation that might be required.

For example if you had a request for work that would require you to modify the schema of the database.  This would not be a massive chunk of work if you had a database per client.  If you had a single database with a table to tenant out your clients access then bespoke changes effect all clients and this may have unwanted consequences.

By having separate databases, however, you are adding to the overhead of maintainability.  Ideally you should keep either code migrations or SQL scripts for the Schema generation for each client (and version them) ideally you would baseline core functionality and rather than alter core tables in the database add functionality with new tables.  This can become quite complex in managing bug fixes where a client has had bespoke changes made to the schema of the database and you are patching in new functionality or simply fixing a known bug.

Lastly security is easier to manage with multiple databases per client. Security is clearly defined per database.

If you have 1 database then unless you are fastidious in implementing the client tenanting functionality then a bug could lead to a data breach.  Ideally you would want to ensure that you have adequate unit tests to cover any tenanted functionality.  Data breaches can be treated quite harshly in many countries. For example in the UK data breaches of personal data could earn you a fine in excess of £100,000.

Overall though I think this would come down to personal preference rather than best practice.

Comment: Thank you actually believe customizations were not very usual, everyone would be administered by the same application. Technically we evaluated the impact of each with its pros and cons, I want to get even in the best practice for this scenario.

Comment: I am not sure that there is best practice as such. Microsoft offer many applications where tenanting is possible with a single database.  It's implementing to correctly that counts.